# C++ Reads/Writes XML without CLR

Tags: c++, xml

I know this is a very stupid question and I'm very new to C++.

I'm developing Starcraft AI, it is DLL file. I'm trying to use XML to gather some data to the bot, however whenever I build the DLL with /clr option. The bot doesn't load properly. So, my question is what is CLR and is there a way to read/write XML without using /clr build option.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

> The /clr compiler option enables the
>   use of Managed Extensions for C++ and
>   creates an output file that will
>   require the .NET Framework common
>   language runtime at run time.
>   (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s%28VS.71%29.aspx))

Starcraft is probably not developed under CLR (.NET Framework runtime).

Answer (score 1):

I've used the free tinyxml library from C++ code - it was quick to get running and reasonably efficient. Well, about as efficient as it's possible for XML to be, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Starcraft probably won't run .NET binaries. You would have to either write your own XML parser, which probably isn't for you seeing as you are new to C++, or find a C++ library that can do it for you.

Example of one:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/